# Two web.configs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

ASP.Net MVC applications has two `web.config`s. One in the root folder and one in the `View`s folder. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Pro ASP.NET MVC 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865) book:

/Views/Web.config:

> This is not your application’s main
>   Web.config file. It just contains a
>   directive instructing the web server
>   not to serve any *.aspx files under
>   /Views (because they should be
>   rendered by a controller, not invoked
>   directly like classic Web Forms *.aspx
>   files). This file also contains
>   configuration needed to make the
>   standard ASP.NET ASPX page compiler
>   work properly with ASP.NET MVC view
>   syntax.

Answer (score 2):

One reason is to simplify your views and your pages. You can put the compilation or even the masterPageFile declaration from your views in this web.config, for example.
Phil Haack did a great post on this -> http://haacked.com/archive/2009/08/04/views-on-a-diet.aspx

Comment: it's actually not a main reason of having a separate web.config but yes it adds some neat extra functionality.